# Django south illogical error

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

So I am using [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for my django project, and have been changing some model logic. I changed a bunch of things, but regardless, my model looks like this **now**:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    '''table of organizational groups'''
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True) #name of group as string
    icon_path_clicked = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255) #location icon is stored
    icon_path_unclicked = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255) #location icon is stored
    group_description = models.CharField(max_length=255) #description of the group
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

now previously, both `icon_path_clicked` and `icon_path_unclicked` had `unique=True`, but I took that out, yet when I try and migrate, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "everything_group_icon_path_clicked_key"
DETAIL:  Key (icon_path_clicked)=() is duplicated.
```

**why is it still treating this as if I no longer have that field as unique?**

## full traceback

```
Running migrations for app:
 - Migrating forwards to 0013_auto__chg_field_group_icon_path_clicked__chg_field_group_icon_path_unc.
 > everything:0007_auto__add_field_group_icon_path_clicked__add_field_group_icon_path_unc
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "everything_group" ADD COLUMN "icon_path_clicked" varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT '';
The error was: could not create unique index "everything_group_icon_path_clicked_key"
DETAIL:  Key (icon_path_clicked)=() is duplicated.

Error in migration: everything:0007_auto__add_field_group_icon_path_clicked__add_field_group_icon_path_unc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 230, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 305, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 134, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 115, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 85, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/Users/ryansaxe/Documents/project/app/migrations/0007_auto__add_field_group_icon_path_clicked__add_field_group_icon_path_unc.py", line 14, in forwards
    keep_default=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 47, in _cache_clear
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 418, in add_column
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 282, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "everything_group_icon_path_clicked_key"
DETAIL:  Key (icon_path_clicked)=() is duplicated.
```

Comment: What is `everything_group_icon_path_clicked_key`? Where does `_key` come from?

Comment: That is created when there is a unique field I believe, but this field is not supposed to be unique anymore...

Comment: Have you manually edited the table to make it non-unique?

Comment: @SimeonVisser I have not manually edited the table.

Comment: Is dropping the table an option for you? Just run syndb again afterwards.

Comment: @wendy_winter there is already a significant amount of data in the db

Comment: @RyanSaxe: have you ran these migrations before or on a different machine? I don't see how you're at migration `0013` but migration `0007` fails to work. It seems your database already has the uniqueness constraint but the migration tries to add it. So it's either a bug in South or you've manually made a mistake along the way.